# Getting a list of all the abstract base classes a given Python class implements

Tags: python, python-3.x

Given a class (in Python 3.8), how can I get a list of all the abstract base classes it implments?  For example, given `list`, I'm looking for something that would return `Container`, `Iterable`, `Collection`, `Sized`, `Sequence`, etc.

`inspect.getmro()`, `__mro__`, and `__bases__` will provide the parent classes, but they do not include the abstract base classes.  So for `list` they only provide `object` (and `list` itself for the mro ones).

`isinstance` will tell if an object implements one single specific abstract base class, but not a list of all abstract base classes it implements.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `collections.abc`. According to python docs

> This module provides abstract base classes that can be used to test whether a class provides a particular interface; for example, whether it is hashable or whether it is a mapping.

Link - https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html

```
In [22]: import collections.abc

In [23]: import inspect

In [31]: [(k,v) for k, v in vars(collections.abc).items() if inspect.isclass(v) and issubclass(list, v) ]
Out[31]:
[('Iterable', collections.abc.Iterable),
 ('Reversible', collections.abc.Reversible),
 ('Sized', collections.abc.Sized),
 ('Container', collections.abc.Container),
 ('Collection', collections.abc.Collection),
 ('Sequence', collections.abc.Sequence),
 ('MutableSequence', collections.abc.MutableSequence)]
```

Comment: This answer does satisfy the case I asked about (getting the collections.abc interfaces).  I was hoping there was a generic way to get a list of all the interfaces a class implements even if I don't know what all the possible ones are - like what System.Reflection provides in .NET.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible because of the way Python handles duck typing in abstract base classes. Using `__subclasshook__` an abc can specify any arbitrary logic to determine if a given class is a subclass of it. For example, from the[`__subclasshook__ documentation`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html#abc.ABCMeta.__subclasshook__):

```py
class MyIterable(ABC):
    # <snipped>
    @classmethod
    def __subclasshook__(cls, C):
        if cls is MyIterable:
            if any("__iter__" in B.__dict__ for B in C.__mro__):
                return True
        return NotImplemented
```

This code says that the class `C` is a subclass of `MyIterable` if it contains the method `__iter__`. If you have an arbitrary class `X` that contains `__iter__` it is a subclass of `MyIterable` even though `X` never expressly extends or is even aware of the existence of `MyIterable`. Therefore, the only way to discover if a given class is a subclass of a set of abstract classes is to check each of them using `issubclass`.

Given that the "subset of abstract bases classes" that you want to check is the set of all abstract base classes, and since there can be an infinite number of arbitrary abstract base classes in the world, it is not possible to test them all.

Of course, this is Python where nothing is truly private. It is technically possible to see all of the classes that are currently imported into your code by recursively scanning `sys.modules`, and testing against all of them using `issubclass`, but I can't imagine this being feasible in any real-world program.